# Variable must be define in pass 1

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I am going through a code of assembly language programming.

```
If IBM
IBM EQU 0
ELSE
IBM EQU 1
```

When I want to run above given code part then the assembler gives the error "variable IBM must be define in pass 1"

Please guide me that how can I define the variables in pass 1.

Comment: What if you use `IFDEF` instead of `IF`. `IFDEF` will check to see if the symbol has actually been previously defined.

Comment: So, you want to say that if IBM is something then make it 0 otherwise make it 1??

Comment: This is a very odd construct.  By doing `If IBM`, you are saying that IBM will already have a value, right?  I mean how could the `If` decide which branch to use if it didn't already have a value?  But given the error you are getting, IBM *doesn't* already have a value. So the poor assembler is looking at this code and it can't figure out what branch to take.  It looks like you are confused about how to use If here, but we can't help you unless you give us a better idea what you're doing. Perhaps you're not clear on the difference between `if` and `cmp`?